# Finding the inverse function of an interpolating function given by NDSolve

Tags: plotting, inverse

Consider the following solution of NDSolve

```
tf = 100;
sol = NDSolve[{x'[t] == -x[t] + 0.1 y[t] + x[t]^2 y[t], 
    y'[t] == 0.5 - 0.1 y[t] - x[t]^2 y[t], x[0] == 0.5, y[0] == 1.5},
   {x, y}, {t, 0, tf}];
xFunc = x /. First@sol;
Plot[xFunc[t], {t, 0, tf}]
```

The plot produces
[image]

How can I obtain the inverse function of `xFunc[t]`, such that the plot will produce

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Maybe like so:

```
tf = 100;
sol = NDSolve[{x'[t] == -x[t] + 0.1 y[t] + x[t]^2 y[t], 
y'[t] == 0.5 - 0.1 y[t] - x[t]^2 y[t], x[0] == 0.5, 
y[0] == 1.5}, {x, y}, {t, 0, tf}];
xFunc = x /. First@sol;
ParametricPlot[{xFunc[t], t}, {t, 0, tf}, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

Thanks to a good suggestion of [user Michael E2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/4999/michael-e2)

```
 ParametricPlot[{xFunc[t], -t}, {t, 0, tf}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
 Ticks -> {Automatic, Charting`ScaledTicks[{-# &, -# &}]}]
 Rotate[Plot[xFunc[t], {t, 0, tf}], -90 Degree](*and  My try :P *)
```

Comment: I've tried that, but in this manner, ScalingFunctions can not be used in parametric plot, and the plot can not be reversed.

Comment: @jarhead. What ScalingFunctions do you need?

Comment: It needs to be reversed as In the figure in the question. In any case the inverse function is needed as well.

Comment: @jarhead The function does not have inverse function (not one-to-one/injective).  Please clarify.

Comment: ``ParametricPlot[{xFunc[t], -t}, {t, 0, tf}, AspectRatio -> 1, Ticks -> {Automatic, Charting`ScaledTicks[{-# &, -# &}]}]`` gives the desired graphics, I think.